# Electron and Express

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, electron, ipc

Here is the problem I am trying to solve.

I want to build an electron app that uses `aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2`. But on windows this sdk won't work with electron. AWS won't support it as well. `aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2` does work with node on windows.

One solution, is to run the `aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2` in an express server. This will be a separate process to electron. This means there will be two `exe` files. One for the express server and one for the electron app. I need to have run the exe files at the same time. Maybe use a bat file.

The express server will be a middle man that will expose some APIs for the electron app to run `aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2`. I can use websockets between electron app and express server.

Base upon this blog. Express server with electron has lots security risks.

https://blog.samuelattard.com/using-express-inside-electron/

To reduce the security risk, I can make the express server only accept internal requests, not from public internet. Ports will be closed to the public. Maybe use a token for authentication.

Any other suggestions?

https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc might be a good alternative to express

Comment: `node-ipc` is a good fit for me.

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't work with electron? What difference does it make if you run it as a separate process? In documentation it says that the `AWS IoT Device Client` only runs on Linux. So i can't see how running it as another process on windows solve this.